# Invalid use of void expression error when using the for_Each algorithm

Tags: c++, foreach

I'm getting an `error: invalid use of void expression` error within my `draw_all_seq_inside2` method!

```
template <typename Container>
void draw_all_seq_inside(Container &c, const rectangle &w){
    typename Container::iterator iter;
    for(iter = c.begin() ; iter != c.end() ; iter++){
            (*iter)->inside_window(w._btm_left, w._top_right);
    }
}

template <typename Container>
void draw_all_seq_inside2(Container &c, const rectangle &w){
    for_each(c.begin(),c.end(),draw_all_seq_inside(c, w));
}
```

I'm calling the `draw_all_seq_inside` within the `for_each algorthim`, am I doing this the correct way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for_each(c.begin(),c.end(),draw_all_seq_inside(c, w));
```

The third argument should be a callable-entity. That is, it could be a function object, or function pointer which can accepts one argument of type of the element of container `c`.

But in your code, you're calling the function and passing the returned value (which is `void`) as third argument to `std::for_each`. That is the cause of the error.

Comment: Cheers Nawaz, still trying to get my head around it but thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

The third parameter to `for_each` is a function object that takes a single parameter. `for_each` will then iterate over the sequence specified by the first and second parameters and pass the value of every element over to that function object.

`for_each` is useful when it's less verbose to use than to write a `for` loop. It doesn't look like it's the case here, but if you *really* want to use `for_each`, you have about only one option.

Write a class:

```
template <typename Container>
void draw_all_seq_inside2(Container &c, const rectangle &w) {

    class Func
    {
        const rectangle & _w;
    public:
        Func(const rectangle &w) : _w(w) {}

        void operator()(/* type here */ * val)
        {
            val->inside_window(_w._btm_left, _w._top_right);
        }
    };
    for_each(c.begin(),c.end(), Func(w));
}
```

This code only seems to work for a C++11-compliant compiler. If you use a C++03 implementation, move the class definition outside of `draw_all_seq_inside2`.

Comment: I think, since `Func` is a local class, it cannot be used in a function template (I'm not sure though).

Comment: Local classes can be used as template parameters in C++11. Not in C++03. So given an up-to-date compiler, this code *should* be fine.

Comment: Oops, my bad, I'll add a note.